# What's the idiomatic why to document the types in a Vuex state definition?

Tags: vue.js, types, vuex, documentation, jsdoc

We have a pretty big state in one component, where the code is like

```
export default {
  someObject: {},
  someOtherObject: {},
  evenMore: []
  <etc...>
}
```

Without any types, it's hard to figure out what's going on. We cannot use Typescript at the moment. Are there an idiomatic way to use e.g. JSDoc to document the types? Something like

```
export default {
  /** @var SomeClass */
  someObject: {},
  /** @var SomeOtherClass
  someOtherObject: {},
  /** String[] */
  evenMore: []
  <etc...>
}
```

Or would that be too noisy? What's the standard Vue practice?

**Edit**: Here's an example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-vuex-plugin#the-state

> ```
> /**
>  * The Vuex 'state' object.
>  * @name State
>  * @type {object} 
>  * @property {boolean} boolProp This property is a boolean.
>  * @property {string} strProp This property is a string.
>  * @property {number} numProp This property is a number.
>  */
> ```

Comment: personally, I'm using jsdoc for my coding, since it works decently with vscode. Although `@property` with `@typedef` doesn't work well in vscode

Comment: @A.Lau Can you post an answer with an example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It more or less depends on what IDE you're using. I'm using VSCode and it understands types very well, I only need to make explicit jsdoc comments under certain situations.

So with export default, instead of exporting the object like:

```
export default {
  /** @var SomeClass */
  someObject: {},
  /** @var SomeOtherClass
  someOtherObject: {},
  /** String[] */
  evenMore: []
  <etc...>
}
```

you need to do:

```
const export_me = {
    /** @var SomeClass */
    someObject: {},
    /** @var SomeOtherClass
    someOtherObject: {},
    /** String[] */
    evenMore: []
  }

export default export_me
```

And with functions, if you're not destructuring them in the parameters, you will need to do something like this

```
/** 
  @typedef {{
    name: string,
    age: number
  }} Person
  @param {Person} person
  @param {number} speed

  @returns {number}
*/
export function runningMan (person, speed) {
    const {
        name,
        age
    } = person;
}
```

I do not use `@property` because it doesn't work in vscode.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a comment on my edit? This link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-vuex-plugin

Comment: if you want to ask these kind of questions, there's a discord for Vue. Look for Vue Land

Comment: I'm already using the IRC channel. But chatting does not create "googleability". :)